# PowerShell to Copy To Clipboard Using -File

Tags: powershell

I have an application that is able to call/execute Powershell and send commands while doing so.

Unfortunately, part of those commands that I need it to send, contains multi-line text with quotes.

Because of this, my solution needs to store the that data into a variable/file, that can be referenced via powershell when the application sends the command arguments.

I'm able to store this as Copy.PS1

```
$command = 'Set-Clipboard -Value @"
Final text
Text also here
"@'

$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
```

Then I try calling Powershell, while sending the arguments:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy bypass -EncodedCommand $encodedCommand -File "Copy.PS1"
```

This process doesn't work. Nor are there any errors that display. It simply doesn't update the clipboard.

However, when I open Powershell ISE, and run it without referencing a File, everything works:

```
$command = 'Set-Clipboard -Value @"
Final text
Text also here
"@'

$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)

powershell -ExecutionPolicy bypass -EncodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

Can someone explain why this behavior is so different?

Comment: You start Powershell and provide an encoded command _AND_ a file? Why that? I'd expect  one of it - not both. I'd recommend using a here string and copy that to the clipboard.

Comment: Hmmm... not sure I follow. The encoded command is so the variable $command is fully escaped because it can contain other commands/HTML.

Comment: Where are you calling the PowerShell CLI (`powershell.exe`) from? I thought `$encodedCommand` is inside the `Copy.ps1` file, why would you also pass it via the CLI? Please clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend keeping it as simple as possible. If you want to have a string running accross multiple lines copied to the clipboard do exactly this ... not more:

```
$HereString = @'
Some arbitrary
String running
accross multiple
lines
'@
Set-Clipboard -Value $HereString
```

Save this to a file "Copy.PS1" and run it with this command line:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy bypass -File Copy.PS1
```

Comment: the OP wants to get the commands encoded. Your example is completely different.

Comment: @WasifHasan Are you sure about what the OP wants?  ;-) I had the impression that he didn't even know exactly what he wants. Let's wait for his answer.

Comment: Definitely just trying to piece it together. Thanks everyone for the help. I don't need encoded information, only if that's going to be helpful at sending the data to Powershell. Usually you need to encode information, otherwise special characters can be problematic.

Comment: @Mrbobdou OK. So did you try the suggestions you've got so far? Did it work? One of them? All of them? Which one is the one you like? If not - what did not work? Could you at least give a status?

Comment: Much appreciate the help across the board. Your solution Olaf is exactly what I need to do. I figured that my data $HereString could be encoded and then sent encoded, to ensure that if there happened to be anything that broke because of bad characters, it would be fine since it was encoded. Is that not necessary here?